# Chef Ruby dig Wrong Number of Arguments

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to do something very simple with Chef/Ruby. All I want to do is check if a key in my hash is `nil` in a safe and clean manner.

Here is my code:

```
if node.dig('k1', 'k2', 'k3').nil?
  myvar1 = node['kA']['kB']['kC']
else
  myvar1 = node['k1']['k2']['k3']
end
```

However, I am getting a `Recipe Compile Error` stating:

```
ArgumentError
-------------
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have read the documentation for `dig` here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig but it doesn't seem to be helping

I am using Ruby 2.3

Comment: It looks like the `dig` method you're using isn't the one documented. What is `node`? Is it a plain Hash or is it something else? Did any code patch in another `dig` method? One way to find out: `node.method(:dig).source_location`.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from the lines of code that you specified? None of those calls would reasonably take zero arguments.

Comment: *"(given 1, expected 0)"* -- the method you've shown above is being given **3** arguments, so it cannot be the source of the error. What's the full stack trace? I think you're looking at the wrong line of code.

Comment: additionally `node` is not a `Hash` it is a `Chef::Node` and does not have a `dig` method so I am assuming this line of code is not even hit or you would get a `NoMethodError` rather than an `ArgumentError` if you wanted to "dig" it would probably be `node.attributes.dig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `node` is not a hash, but rather a node object, so `.dig()` does not work. I ended up using the following:

```
if node.read('k1', 'k2', 'k3').nil?
  myvar1 = node['kA']['kB']['kC']
else
  myvar1 = node['k1']['k2']['k3']
end
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you want `node.read`, not `node.attributes.read`.

Comment: What's the difference? `node.attributes.read` seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: By convention you should not access methods on `node.attributes` directly, it's an internal object. Any public methods that should be used are forwarded from the node object.

Answer (score 4):

We didn’t add that to the API supported by the node above the because it overlapped with the existing `node.read` method which is what you want to use here. It looks like a hash, but only supports a subset of the methods.

EDIT: Now that I'm not on mobile the full code you want is probably:

```
node.read('k1', 'k2', 'k3') || node.read('kA', 'kB', 'kC')
```

Unless `false` is a valid value.